# Fiber is not domain for $a\neq 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Let $S=k[x,t]\times k[t,t^{-1}]$ as algebra over $k[t]$. Fiber $S/(t-a)S$ over $(t-a)\subset k[t]$ is not domain for $a\neq 0$.

I failed to find the example to see this is not domain when $a\neq 0$. If $a=0$, $S/(t-a)S=k[x]$ clearly a domain.

Comment: The fiber over $t=a$, with $a \neq 0$ is isomorphic to $k[x] \times k$ which is obviously not a domain, geometrically it is the disjoint union of a point and an affine line.

Comment: $S/(t-a)S\simeq (k[x,t]/(t-a)k[x,t])\times(k[t,t^{-1}]/(t-a)k[t,t^{-1}])\simeq\cdots$.